"run all chunks above" button does not work in R markdown
Since some weeks I have to manually run every chunk in my R script and the "run all chunks above" button does often not work or leaves specific chunks out. I have the newest version of R studio and R base. Did anyone else encounter or solve this issue ? I would really need help as my script is quite long...
Thank you!
I reinstalled all versions and checked all chunks
